# Object changes in child class widget traverse back to parent class widget where it was initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on cart item in Flutter application. Right now I am working on editing cart item. The structure of my code is such that each cart item is a `StatefulWidget`. When I click on edit cart item I am showing a custom dialog box with extras, being selected for that item. For that purpose I am passing an object of cart item to dialog box and retrieving data to show in dialog box.

The issue I am facing in this case is that If I select some other extras in a dialog box while editing cart item and then close the dialog to discard new changes it still reflect those new changes in selected cart item. But the fact is I am not updating that cart item in case of discarding those new changes.

Here are my some code snippets. In the code below I am calling the extras dialog box from cart item widget class:

```html
Future modifierDialog() {
    return showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black45,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation,
          Animation secondaryAnimation) {
        return Dialog(
          child: ModifiersDialogWidget(
            menuItem: item.copyWith(),
            setSelection: (selectedItem, extras) {
             
              HotKeysWidget.of(context)!.editCartItem(selectedItem, extras);
            },
            editItem: true,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This is my custom dialog box code of extras. In `ModifiersWidget` I am actually showing all extras and selecting/unselecting extras.

```html
class ModifiersDialogWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Food menuItem;
  final Function(Food, List<Map<String, dynamic>>) setSelection; /////to save changes + add to cart
  final bool editItem;   ///////null if it is not edit cart item

  const ModifiersDialogWidget({
    required this.menuItem,
    required this.setSelection,
    required this.editItem,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return ModifiersDialogWidgetState();
  }
}

class ModifiersDialogWidgetState extends State<ModifiersDialogWidget> {
  late Future<Map<String, dynamic>> data;
  bool changesMade = false;
  final GlobalKey<ModifiersWidgetState> modifierKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    data = fetchTimeline();
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchTimeline() async {
    /////////////COUNT TOTAL NUMBER OF REQUIRED MODIFIERS
    int totalRequiredModifiers = 0;
    for (var object in widget.menuItem.modifiers) {
      if (object.required) ++totalRequiredModifiers;
      object.selected = false;
    }
    widget.menuItem.totalPrice = widget.menuItem.price;
    /////////////SET FOR SELECTED MODIFIERS AND ADD THEN TO LIST
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> selectedExtras = [];
    if (widget.editItem) {
      for (var modifier in widget.menuItem.selectedModifiers) {
        int modIndex = widget.menuItem.modifiers
            .indexWhere((element) => element.id == modifier.id);
        widget.menuItem.modifiers[modIndex].selected = true;
        for (var extra in modifier.extras) {
          int extraIndex = widget.menuItem.modifiers[modIndex].extras
              .indexWhere((element) => element.id == extra.id);
          widget.menuItem.modifiers[modIndex].extras[extraIndex].selected =
              true;
          selectedExtras.add(
            {
              'extra_id': extra.id,
              'extraname': extra.name,
              'price': extra.originalPrice,
            },
          );
          widget.menuItem.totalPrice =
              widget.menuItem.totalPrice + extra.originalPrice;
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      'foodItem': Food(
        widget.menuItem.id.toString(),
        widget.menuItem.name,
        widget.menuItem.price,
        widget.menuItem.price,
        widget.menuItem.image,
        widget.menuItem.description,
        widget.menuItem.ingredients,
        1,
        widget.menuItem.chefSpecial,
        widget.menuItem.off,
        widget.menuItem.totalPrice,
        0.0,
        widget.menuItem.totalExtraPrice,
        widget.menuItem.available,
        [],
        [],
        widget.menuItem.printerID,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        widget.menuItem.extrasIDS,
        widget.menuItem.modifiers,
        widget.menuItem.selectedModifiers,
        widget.menuItem.modifierExist,
        widget.menuItem.openPrice,
        'false',
        'none',
        false,
        '',
        0.0,
        widget.menuItem.GST,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0,
        '',
        '',
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        [],
        null,
      ),
      'totalRequired': totalRequiredModifiers,
      'selectedExtras': selectedExtras,
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.70,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.90,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.grey[400],
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      'Modifiers',
                      style: AppTextStyles().style2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 35,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: data,
                builder:
                    (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                      ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                      : ModifiersWidget(
                          key: modifierKey,
                          data: snapshot.data,
                          setSelection: (item, extras) {
                            widget.setSelection(item, extras);
                          },
                          showConfirmation: () {
                            changesMade = true;
                          },
                        );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ModifiersWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic>? data;
  Function(Food, List<Map<String, dynamic>>) setSelection;
  VoidCallback showConfirmation;

  ModifiersWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
    required this.setSelection,
    required this.showConfirmation,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return ModifiersWidgetState();
  }
}

class ModifiersWidgetState extends State<ModifiersWidget> {
  bool status = true;
  bool isLoading = false;
  late List<Modifier> modifiers;
  late Modifier currentModifier;
  final GlobalKey<ModifierOptionsState> optionsKeys = GlobalKey();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<String> requiredFilledModifiers = [];
  late Food menuItem;
  late String errorTxt;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> extraItems = [];
  bool changesMade = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    errorTxt = '';
    initData();
    super.initState();
  }

  initData() {
    menuItem = widget.data!['foodItem'];
    menuItem.GSTPrice = (menuItem.totalPrice * (menuItem.GST / 100));
    modifiers = menuItem.modifiers;
    currentModifier = modifiers[0];
    currentModifier.selected = true;
    if (menuItem.selectedModifiers.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < menuItem.selectedModifiers.length; i++) {
        requiredFilledModifiers.add(menuItem.selectedModifiers[i].id);
      }
      print('SELECTED MODIFIER IN STATE CLASS: $requiredFilledModifiers');
    }
    extraItems = widget.data!['selectedExtras'];
  }
  
}
```

This is my model class:

```html
class Food {
  String id;
  String name;
  double
      price; ///////////ORIGINAL PRICE OF ITEM SINGLE ITEM EXCLUDING EXTRAS IF EXIST
  double
      singleItemPrice; //////SINGLE QUAN PRICE OF CART ITEM IN HOTKEYS INCLUDING EXTRAS IF EXIST
  String image;
  String description;
  String ingredients;
  int quantity;
  bool chefSpecial;
  double off;
  double totalPrice; /////INCLUDES GST AND EXTRAS IF EXIST
  double cost; ///////TOTAL PRICE OF ITEM - TOTAL GST PRICE
  double
      totalExtraPrice; //////////////////TOTAL EXTRA PRICE SELECTED FOR ITEM IN CART
  bool available;
  List<Extra>
      extras; //////////EXTRAS WHICH HAVE BEEN SELECTED FOR THE ITEM (FOR ORDER USE ONLY)
  List<String> categoryName;
  String printerID;
  bool kioskValue;
  bool dineinValue;
  bool mobileValue;
  List<String> extrasIDS;
  List<Modifier> modifiers;
  List<Modifier> selectedModifiers;
  bool modifierExist;
  bool openPrice;
  String hidden;
  String color;
  bool selected;
  String note;
  double GSTPrice; /////TOTAL GST FOR MORE THAN ONE ITEM IN CART
  double GST; ////////SINGLE GST VALUE
  double perDiscount;

  ///AMOUNT OF % DISC IF GIVEN ON ITEM IN HOTKEYS
  double dollarDiscount; //AMOUNT OF $ DISC IFF GIVEN ON ITEM IN HOTKEYS
  double
      overridePrice; ////// THE NEW OVERRIDE PRICE AFTER +/- ORIGINAL ITEM PRICE
  double newDiscPrice; //AMOUNT OF DISC GIVEN ON ITEM EITHER % DISC OR $ DISC
  int cartCount;

  ///QUAN OF ITEM IN CART
  String UPC;
  String productID;
  double per2;
  double per3;
  double per4;
  double per5;
  List<Allergy> allergies;
  Deal?
      dealItem; /////////////IF MENU ITEM TYPE IS DEAL THEN ASSIGN IT OTHERWISE IT IS NULL VALUE

  Food copyWith() => Food(
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.price,
        this.singleItemPrice,
        this.image,
        this.description,
        this.ingredients,
        this.quantity,
        this.chefSpecial,
        this.off,
        this.totalPrice,
        this.cost,
        this.totalExtraPrice,
        this.available,
        this.extras,
        this.categoryName,
        this.printerID,
        this.kioskValue,
        this.dineinValue,
        this.mobileValue,
        this.extrasIDS,
        this.modifiers,
        this.selectedModifiers,
        this.modifierExist,
        this.openPrice,
        this.hidden,
        this.color,
        this.selected,
        this.note,
        this.GSTPrice,
        this.GST,
        this.dollarDiscount,
        this.perDiscount,
        this.overridePrice,
        this.newDiscPrice,
        this.cartCount,
        this.UPC,
        this.productID,
        this.per2,
        this.per3,
        this.per4,
        this.per5,
        this.allergies,
        this.dealItem,
      );

  Food(
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.singleItemPrice,
    this.image,
    this.description,
    this.ingredients,
    this.quantity,
    this.chefSpecial,
    this.off,
    this.totalPrice,
    this.cost,
    this.totalExtraPrice,
    this.available,
    this.extras,
    this.categoryName,
    this.printerID,
    this.kioskValue,
    this.dineinValue,
    this.mobileValue,
    this.extrasIDS,
    this.modifiers,
    this.selectedModifiers,
    this.modifierExist,
    this.openPrice,
    this.hidden,
    this.color,
    this.selected,
    this.note,
    this.GSTPrice,
    this.GST,
    this.dollarDiscount,
    this.perDiscount,
    this.overridePrice,
    this.newDiscPrice,
    this.cartCount,
    this.UPC,
    this.productID,
    this.per2,
    this.per3,
    this.per4,
    this.per5,
    this.allergies,
    this.dealItem,
  );
```

I didn't see any reason of traversing back the changes being made in `ModifiersWidget` to `ModifiersDialogWidget` widget and also the cart item widget itseld.

Anyone kindly help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of passing original instance, maybe try to pass a copy of your item to `ModifiersDialogWidget `.

Comment: The actual manipulation of data is in the ```ModifiersWidget``` widget where extras are shown and selection is made. If you see my code above I am already passing copy of object to that widget. But It clearly didn't work at all.

Comment: I can only see that you are passing it like `menuItem: item`, and you are altering it in `ModifiersWidget` like `widget.menuItem....`, so it's the same instance there and it's reflecting on the parent instance. Try to copy the `item` before passing it with `menuItem: item`. Something like `menuItem: item.copy()` where you can create your `copy()` method in `Food` class.

Comment: I tried copying the instance of object same like this ```menuItem: item.copy()``` but still same issue.

Comment: I have modifier my post above with this change. Kindly have a look.